# What would not allow Excel connection to SSAS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, excel-2007, ssas-2008

2 boxes side by side same Sys Admin user credentials.

XP SP3 with Office 2007 Pro and Native Client 10
Win Server 2008 with SQL 2008 Enterprise SSAS on 2nd instance

Box 1 connects easily every time to OLAP
Box 2 Fails every time with this:

```
Errors in OLE DB Provider - Could Not connect ReDirector - Ensure SQL Browser Service is running
```

Please help collaborate on possible issues.